# display a popup if there are any unsaved data in the flex desktop app

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have to build a functionality to alert the user if there is any unsaved data when the user tries to close the window.

I'm using Flex4 for a desktop application.

Does anyone of you have any idea if there is any method to make it simpler to control the unsaved data of the opened window?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to flag your component saying that it is dirty when ever anything changes. So, there is no inbuild functionality. You have to listen to the change event on each and every field that is important for you

Answer (score 0):

Actually it just needed to prevent the default action of the closing native event. I resolved it like  this:

FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING, appClosing);

protected function appClosing(event:Event):void
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                //then do whatever you want
             }